# Help on creating a table

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I need your help please on creating a table as shown in the following picture. I can create a basic table but I am having problem with the subcells in the middle of it.

I will fill this table with words only if this matters.

Can you please show me how to do it?!

Thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your favorite table. `multirow` and `multicolumn` are your best pets.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Hi                & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                             \\ \hline
                  & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{There}                        \\ \hline
                  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}        & I'm        &       \\ \hline
                  & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                             \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} & A nice       & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Small} &       \\ \cline{2-5} 
                  &              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{}      & Table \\ \hline
                  & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{}                             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Than you so much AboAmmar, I have one thing please. I have long sentences in the cells, the words cross the page and I don't know how to make them contained in the cell. In other words, is there any way to make the table forced to be contained in the center of the page. Thanks!

Comment: I encourage you to post another question for this problem, preferably adding your real text and the exact requirements. That's, specify which columns would contain long sentences and if you prefer the table occupy whole textwidth, etc.